# Android manifest merge error related to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, manifest

I have this error when I try to build my app:

> activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present app main manifest (this file), line 23

I think it is related to Firebase libraries I imported. 
In my manifest I have nothing related to android:launchMode.
Any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I temporarily "fixed" avoiding the use of this library com.google.firebase: firebase-auth: 16.0.5. I still don't know which is the cause of this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Be sure to update all firebase libraries to the latest version